# Change jenkins timezone master/slave?

Tags: jenkins, timezone

I have a jenkins configuration as follows:

Master (ubuntu)

```
~$ date
Tue Mar  7 08:35:06 UTC 2017
```

slave (redhat)

```
# date
Tue Mar  7 08:36:10 PST 2017
```

In jenkins system information the master shows (should show pacific):

```
user.timezone   GMT
```

Even though I have placed these lines from jenkins wiki:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Duser.timezone=America/Los_Angeles"
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/Los_Angeles"
```

And the strangest part is when I check the node configuaration in jenkins it shows my redhat slave node is 8 hours ahead.

My redhat slaves time ideally shouldn't be changed because it would screw with DB writes that I will be doing in testing. However I am completely stumped so any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you placed the JAVA env strings? Could you ensure that they are being used:

```
su jenkins
echo $JAVA_ARGS
echo $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my UTC time was off. When I did timedatectl it showed NTP was working and UTC was in sync but it was lying. My labs firewall blocks the NTP port and I ended up finding this magic command to sync my clock:

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -S  "http://www.google.com/" 2>&1 | grep -E '^[[:space:]]*[dD]ate:' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*[dD]ate:[[:space:]]*//' | head -1l | awk '{print $1, $3, $2,  $5 ,"GMT", $4 }' | sed 's/,//')"
```

It works well I just have to